# Where does the HTML added by the Page editor go?

Tags: wordpress

I know a WordPress page is constructed from

1. The page template assigned to the page,
2. The style sheet assigned to the page, and
3. Some HTML.

And I know you can use the Page editor to insert custom HTML.  But where does this HTML go? The template is a .php file.  The style is a .css file. Is there a file also for the HTML  associated with the page?  Or is there maybe just a database record that holds the HTML, i.e., the HTML that isn't in the template?

Comment: html code goes into the custom .php template file. just so you know a valid html file is also a valid php file.

Comment: @RajKamal OP states `And I know you can use the Page editor to insert custom HTML. But where does this HTML go? `. Steve is asking when he writes html into the post editor, where does it go? He isn't referring to specific templating. Instead he is talking about the content itself.

Answer (score 0):

All of your pages, unless they have a custom structure are being served from the **page.php** file in your themes root. All pages you create via the Page Editor, including the posts are being stored in a table in your database called `wp_posts`

The schema for **wp_posts** is as follows:

[image: wp_posts schema]

The information you are editing in the Post / Page editor including html is stored into **post_content** column in this database table. This includes html, images, hyperlinks, etc.

Go into your sites database and look around, there are a couple of tables which can be seen from the [expanded version of this image](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description).